# Soundcloud php track list

Tags: php, soundcloud

I'm using the following code to get a track list from SoundCloud. The issue is it only returns 200 tracks and not the entire list. Can someone please help.

```
$soundcloud_url = "http://api.soundcloud.com/users/{$userid}/tracks.json?client_id={$clientid}&limit=10000";
$tracks_json = file_get_contents($soundcloud_url); //get tracks
$tracks = json_decode($tracks_json); //convert tracks
```

Answer (score 1):

That is the maximum value of collection items returned by the API, by default it is set to 50 but it can go up to 200.

You can pagine through collections of tracks, check the below code which uses `linked_partitioning` parameters that indicates the response include a `next_href` property that points the next collection:

```
# start paging through results, 100 at a time
tracks = client.get('/tracks', order='created_at', limit=page_size,
                    linked_partitioning=1)
for track in tracks:
    print track.title
```

Check [this](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#search) for detailed info.